# How do i change attributes of a generic attribute of a class?

Tags: java

In my main class i've created object instances of a class that contains generic attributes. With my getters i can read the generic attributes, but with my setters i cant change them. The error eclipse throws at me in my Main class at line 16 is "The method set(capture#2-of ?) in the type Rocket<capture#2-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList)". I'll add the code of my three classes.

```
package dchapter11_1;

public class Rocket<T> {
      private T value;

      public Rocket() {}
      public Rocket( T value ) { this.value = value; }
      
      public void set(T value) { this.value = value; }
      public T get() { return value; }

      @Override
      public String toString() {
          return getClass() + "[value=" + value.toString() + "]";
      }
      public boolean isEmpty() { return value == null; }
      public void empty() { value = null; }
}
```

```
package dchapter11_1;

public class Player {
          public String name;
          public Rocket<?> rightRocket;
          public Rocket<?> leftRocket;
          
          public Player(String name, Rocket<?> leftRocket, Rocket<?> rightRocket) {
              this.name = name;
              this.leftRocket = leftRocket;
              this.rightRocket = rightRocket;
          }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public Rocket<?> getRightRocket() {
            return rightRocket;
        }
        public void setRightRocket(Rocket<?> rightRocket) {
            this.rightRocket = rightRocket;
        }
        public Rocket<?> getLeftRocket() {
            return leftRocket;
        }
        public void setLeftRocket(Rocket<?> leftRocket) {
            this.leftRocket = leftRocket;
        }
        
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return getClass() + "[name=" + name + ", rightRocket=" + rightRocket.toString() + ", leftRocket=" + leftRocket.toString() + "]";
        }
}
```

```
package dchapter11_1;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("serial")
        Player kleinerB = new Player("kleinerK", new Rocket<Integer>(Integer.valueOf(42)), new Rocket<ArrayList<String>>(new ArrayList<>(){{add("BU"); add("BU"); add("BU");}}));
        System.out.println(kleinerB.toString());
        
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = (ArrayList<String>)kleinerB.getRightRocket().get();
        for(String s : arrayList) {
            System.out.print(s);
        }
        //kleinerB.getRightRocket().set(new ArrayList<String>()); //FUNKTIONIERT NICHT KEINER WEISS WARUM
    }
}
```

I've tried to change the type of the Rocket attributes in player from `<?>` to `<T>`, but that only gives me the option to create `Player` instances from a specific type (what I specifically don't want).

Comment: Unrelated but `new ArrayList<>(){{add("BU"); add("BU"); add("BU");}}` would probably be a lot more readable as `new ArrayList<>(List.of("BU", "BU", "BU"))`

Comment: If you want to be able to get strongly typed Rockets out of a Player, then Player will need 1 generic type parameter for each rocket. e.g. `Player<Foo, Bar> player = new Player...` Alternatively, in this case you can just keep a reference to the Rocket as a local variable before passing it to the Player constructor. Then rather than call `kleinerB.getRightRocket()` you can just refer to the local variable: https://ideone.com/ammNbG

Comment: You can use `kleinerB.setRightRocket(new Rocket<>(new ArrayList<String>()));` But what’s the point of it? After you’ve set it, nobody knows that the list you’ve set is a `List<String>`. The entire use of Generics is pointless here. It’s not even clear why you wrap the objects in a `Rocket` object. It does not add anything useful.

Comment: Unrelated again, but wouldn't it make more sense to have `rightRocket` on the right of `leftRocket` in `Player`'s constructor parameters list? It took me a while to realize that the error was *not* that you were trying to set an `ArrayList<Integer>` to a new `ArrayList<String>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty resolution to your problem is to declare erased types in getXxxRocket methods, like this:

```java
    public <R> Rocket<R> getRightRocket() {
        return (Rocket<R>) rightRocket;
    }

    public <L> Rocket<L> getLeftRocket() {
        return (Rocket<L>) leftRocket;
    }
```

But you'll have to use an unchecked cast in order to make it work.

The best option here seems to use generics in the Player class, like this:

```java
public class Player<R, L> {
    public String name;
    public Rocket<R> rightRocket;
    public Rocket<L> leftRocket;

    public Player(String name, Rocket<R> rightRocket, Rocket<L> leftRocket) {
        this.name = name;
        this.rightRocket = rightRocket;
        this.leftRocket = leftRocket;
    }

...

    public Rocket<R> getRightRocket() {
        return rightRocket;
    }

    public Rocket<L> getLeftRocket() {
        return leftRocket;
    }

...
```

And then you can instantiate the Player class like this:

```java
Player<List<String>, Integer> kleinerB = 
    new Player<>("kleinerK", new Rocket<>(List.of("BU", "BU", "BU")), new Rocket<>(42));
```

BTW, never use concrete types (ArrayList) in declarations when you can use their interfaces (List).

Comment: So i can't really create a Player implementation, thus instances take any type of rocket after declaration while the code is running can i? (while trying to keep the code somewhat conventional)

Comment: The first part of my answer will do it, but it is really not type-safe and maybe you should drop the generic types and only use Object. Generics are there to help type safety.

Comment: The first part is completely broken and you should not suggest it at all, not to speak of burying the information that this is not type safe in a comment below the answer. This code allows to do something like `Rocket<String> a = player.getRightRocket(); Rocket<Integer> b = player.getRightRocket(); a.set(""); Integer i = b.get();`

Comment: That's exactly what i asked for. It's unconventional and not typesafe and there's no other way to do it. Kept reading the script i worked with and learned that generics in java are just really badly designed in general. Won't be using them apart from some cases, they don't guarantee typesafety anyway 90% of the time.

Comment: @Holger the information is not buried, I started saying that it's a dirty solution, and sometimes it's what you need to solve a problem. That's why java gave us the SuppressWarnings annotation after all.

Comment: @Tired8296 java generics are not badly designed, they were designed that way to allow backward compatibility and that was a good thing. It is the other way around, if well applied it is very very useful and guarantees type safety 90% of the times :)

Comment: @Tired8296 what you are trying to do, as far as recognizable, wouldn’t work in any language. You are like someone who holds a vase upside-down and complains that it doesn’t hold the water.

Comment: @Vinicius this has nothing to do with backward compatibility. The whole point of Generics is to not allow what the OP is trying to do. There are two kinds of type systems. Those like Java’s where you can make it somehow pass the compiler and break later in funny ways or those preventing it completely. And there’s a difference between being “a dirty resolution” and being “not typesafe”, in other words, completely broken and not a solution at all.

Comment: @Holger I think you misunderstood this: "they were designed THAT WAY to allow backward compatibility". I was answering OP's (and many others) view that generics were badly designed. And quoting Brian Goetz: "It must be possible to evolve an existing non-generic class to be generic in a binary-compatible and source-compatible manner.". So it was implemented in a way to ensure backward compatibility.

Comment: @Holger "The whole point of Generics is to not allow what the OP is trying to do". Completely disagree. First because the language allows this with or without generics. Unchecked casts exists for a reason. And second, generics were created to extend and improve the type system, not to prevent anything. Not that I agree with OP choices, but everyone is entitled to use fragile code that "just works" to solve a problem.

Comment: @Vinicius the purpose of Generics is to help programmers to write reasonable and correct code. So if a programmer tries to write unreasonable code, it is not fitting the purpose of Generics, whether it is possible to write the code or not. And when the OP accuses Generics for being “badly designed” because it doesn’t support writing unreasonable code that only pretends to be generic while actually being totally unsafe, this has nothing to do with the trade-offs mentioned by Brian Goetz et al. In fact your first “solution” is relying on those compromises.

Comment: @Holger Please pay more attention to what I'm writing or else this is a pointless discussion. I cited Brian Goetz to counter what you said about backward compatibility and there is nothing in my text that says anything about trade-offs in using them. I KNOW that the purpose of generics and I AGREE with you in this. This doesn't change the point that in Java you CAN write unsafe code, with or without generics, and sometimes this is what you want/need and learning this is a possibility is legit and that's why I put that in my answer, but I also made it clear that this is not the best way to go.